# How can I include Facebook Origami effects in my app?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, quartz-core, origami

Origami - the Facebook prototyping tool has some amazing UI effects.
Is there any way to actually use those when I'm building my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to include animations from origami into your app.

**However**...

Facebook announced Pop a few days ago, which is the animation engine they used in their app 'Paper'. You can hear all about it [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OiY1cheLpmI). And the good news is Pop integrates with Origami, making what you want possible, Pop will be open source (to be released very soon they said), so keep your eyes open for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Code Export" to export animation code in Origami 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Origami is for prototyping animations. If you want them to be real you have code them yourself. There is no export to code feature or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Joris Kuivers has released [qc-mobile](https://github.com/kluivers/qc-mobile) as mentioned in [this blog](http://thechangelog.com/prototype-your-ios-apps-with-quartz-composer-and-qc-mobile/). It is a starting point.